# why does element-ui's validate() function keep clearing server side passed validation (via error prop) errors?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I am using element-ui form validation for validating simple rules on client side to relieve server from additional load. After the initial client side validation passes, I send them to server and do some more (complex) validations on server side.

This works without any problems when I get the returned errors and display them on custom built error fields. But when try to use element-ui's built in error prop to display the errors within the form-item then after the second submit the server side errors disappear from form-item. Even if I hard code the error prop like `error="This is a error message"` the message still disappears after running the validate() method.

here is a sample of the form

```
<el-form :model="form" :rules="rules" ref="form">
    <el-form-item prop="mobile_number" :error="errors.mobile_number[0]">
        <el-input v-model.number="form.mobile_number"> </el-input>
    </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

and this is the part where I submit the form

```
    submitForm(){
        this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
            if (valid) {
                axios.post(url, 
                    this.form
                ).then((response) => {
                    if(response.data.status == 'success'){
                        // do stuff when successful
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

When I remove the validate() method or when i disable the validation rules on client side then the server side remain. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the source that is what I found. The element-ui validate uses the same error message variable (validateMessage) for both internal process and external prop errors.  So when the validate() runs the element-ui is checking its own rules first and if it passes then returns valid true else it creates error and assigns them to the validateMessage.

In the other hand to pass manual errors element ui is using a watcher that watches the error prop.

```
watch: {
error: {
  immediate: true,
  handler: function handler(value) {
    this.validateMessage = value;
    this.validateState = value ? 'error' : '';
  }
},
validateStatus: function validateStatus(value) {
  this.validateState = value;
}
```

},

So to take control of what is assigned to the validateMessage the watcher needs to be triggered which can only be when the error prop changes as long as it remains the same the internal validate process will overwrite the validateMessage.

```
  validator.validate(model, { firstFields: true }, function (errors, invalidFields) {
    _this.validateState = !errors ? 'success' : 'error';
    _this.validateMessage = errors ? errors[0].message : '';

    callback(_this.validateMessage, invalidFields);
    _this.elForm && _this.elForm.$emit('validate', _this.prop, !errors, _this.validateMessage || null);
  });
```

In my case, because client side validation passes the rules validateMessage is set to "" so no errors are displayed even if server side still remain errors.

In short, when the elements server side validator passes valid I clear my local errors just before submitting the form. And let it set them again if any exist. And it works.

```
submitForm(){
    this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
        if (valid) {
            this.errors = [];
            axios.post(url, 
                this.form
            ).then((response) => {
                if(response.data.status == 'success'){
                    // do stuff when successful
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            })
        }
    });
}
```